# Pass curl options to node js http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, curl

I have a curl request to an api that requires a -u parameter to set an username login and a -d to send the data of the post.

This is a template :

```
$ curl -i -X POST "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/workers" \
     -u "c64f80ba83d7cfce8ae74f51e263ce93:" \
     -d '{"name":"Marco Emery","image":"http://cdn3.addy.co/images/marco.png","phone":"415-342-0112","teams":["0pgyktD5f3RpV3gfGZn9HPIt"],"vehicle":{"type":"CAR","description":"Tesla Model 3","licensePlate":"CA 2LOV733","color":"purple"}}'
```

How can i translate both the -u and the -d to a node js request formatted this way ?

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};
```

Or, is it possible to have a url that i could give to my web browser that would take those options into account ?

Comment: have you tried [node-curl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-curl) ?

the **'-u'** can be replaced by a basic authorization header. 
Example: `Authorization: Basic c64f80ba83d7cfce8ae74f51e263ce93:`

Answer (score 4):

From the API documentation, it uses basic HTTP Auth,  where the key string is the username of the request, and the password is blank. So you have to that Authorization header with each request. You could use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to do this:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://onfleet.com/api/v2/workers',
    body: '{"name":"Marco Emery","image":"http://cdn3.addy.co/images/marco.png","phone":"415-342-0112","teams":["0pgyktD5f3RpV3gfGZn9HPIt"],"vehicle":{"type":"CAR","description":"Tesla Model 3","licensePlate":"CA 2LOV733","color":"purple"}}',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer("c64f80ba83d7cfce8ae74f51e263ce93:").toString('base64')
    }
};
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Yes that's what i needed ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) npm module to do this like so:

```
var request = require('superagent');
request
   .post('https://onfleet.com/api/v2/workers')
   .auth('c64f80ba83d7cfce8ae74f51e263ce93', '')
   .send({"name":"Marco Emery","image":"http://cdn3.addy.co/images/marco.png","phone":"415-342-0112","teams":["0pgyktD5f3RpV3gfGZn9HPIt"],"vehicle":{"type":"CAR","description":"Tesla Model 3","licensePlate":"CA 2LOV733","color":"purple"}})
   .end(function(err, res){
         if (res.ok) {
             console.log('yay got ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
          } else {
             console.log('Oh no! error ' + res.text);
          }
   });
```